# set cursor in centre position of textfield

Tags: ios, swift2

I am simply trying to set the cursor position in centre of UITextField when  it it get focus.
i used the following code but it is not working properly as it is objective c and i want to code in swift  so plz suggest how do i do it in swift

```
(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITextPosition *pos = [textField beginningOfDocument];
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:pos
                                                          toPosition:pos]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just Make textfield text alignment center. if you want to change the cursor position write the code in textfieldDidBeginEditing.

Answer (score 0):

It works the same way like obj C

```
textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRangeFromPosition(textField.beginningOfDocument, toPosition: textField.endOfDocument)
```

*Change your From and To positions accordingly